# Check the first line of a file using fileReader in javascript

Tags: javascript, filereader

I have files that I need to check if the first line in the CSV file has a header or not. If it does it will have the word 'symbol' first, if not it will not. So I am going to use this as the criteria for finding the header.

However using fileReader() I am not finding a way to do this? I am familiar with checking for objects however working with the file itself is eluding me.

There are tutorials online for using fileReader() but not that I found do this, can anyone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FileReader.prototype.readAsText()`, `String.prototype.split()` with parameter `\n`, then check if first element in resulting array contains word `"symbol"`

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
.onchange = function(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var text = event.target.result;
    var arr = text.split(/\n/).filter(Boolean);
    if (/symbol/.test(arr[0])) {
      console.log("symbol found", arr[0]);
    }
  }
  reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: @illcrx For example, you can download https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/c1cd0acafba2e790da049c6b49dc79d2/raw/1a0f4b8b2fc19753c40f20f9995f4ce3fd0f6250/symbol.csv , then select file at stacksnippets to check if `"symbol" is found at header of file